# Is there any way to round string-interpolated floats in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scientific-notation

I have an API that serves data in JSON which includes a lot of decimal/float numbers. It so hapens that a lot of these numbers are between 0 and 1, and can sometimes be quite small... small enough that they were occasionally being represented in scientific notation (e.g. `0.00025` was represented as `2.5e-05`). I needed a way to prevent the API from ever serving up numbers in scientific notation, so I wrote this utility function as part of a JSONEncoder for all float numbers:

```
def format_float(self):
    return f"{self:.16f}".rstrip("0").rstrip(".")
```

That way, it would first change a number like `0.000025` to `0.0000250000000000`, then strip the trailing zeroes, leaving the number represented as I'd like to see it. And for whole numbers like `-1`, the formatting was likewise benign, as it removes the trailing zeroes and trailing period.

But I run into a problem with numbers like `1.4`. Run that through my function, and it is now represented as `1.3999999999999999`. Is there some way I can tweak this to ensure it properly rounds up in situations like this?

Comment: Why do you need to prevent it? Is it possible to change the client which accepts the API input?

Comment: Why does the first comment of every question asked on Stack Overflow always have to question _why_ the questioner is doing something in the way they've described, rather than just addressing the question at hand? This happens **every** single time. Comments like that make the experience on Stack Overflow genuinely draining as it is essentially off-topic. I should not have to explain my motivations every single time I'm asking a relatively simple question. Suffice it to say that I cannot change the client; that is out of my control.

Comment: I'm sorry but often people ask for something difficult and there's something easier they could have done, the so-called XY-Problem.